# Is it possible to use Paypal's REST API to query subscriptions made through Paypal's Subscribe Button?

Tags: java, rest, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I keep going back and forth between their REST and Classic API but none seemed very straightforward to me.

I used Paypal's Create Button tool to create the "Subscribe" button and I'm wondering if there's a way to query users subscriptions using Paypal's API (REST preferably). I'm aware of IPN but I would like to be able to query user's subscription status whenever I want.

Comment: Have you solved this issue ? I'm trying to figure out the same thing! Thanks in advance.